# What is DPIs of photo taken in iPad or iPhone camera?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, tesseract

I am using tesseract library  in my application for the image scanning. I have read somewhere that library gives good performance for image that over 100 DPIs.I am capturing the photo with iPhone 4 and iPad and giving it as input of tesseract library.But still library giving unreadable output .What is the DPIs for the iPhone or iPad camera?How can i improve the performance of tesseract library?

Comment: The dots per inch depends on how far the camera is from the object it is photographing.  It's not a constant value.

Comment: That "image > 100 DPI" hint must be from somebody who has no clue what the DPI measure actually means. I doubt tesseract would recognize a 3 pixel character on an image shown at 600 DPI. What you need to know is how big the characters should be in the image, which has nothing to do with DPI. @robmayoff has given the only reasonable answer to this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a 12 inch ruler and a tape measure.  Put the ruler on the table.  Hold the phone above the ruler, pointing the camera at the ruler.  Use the tape measure to measure the distance from the ruler to the camera.  Take a photo of the ruler.

Open the photo in an image viewer or editor.  (You can use Preview on the Mac, for example.)  Use the image viewer/editor to measure the size of the ruler in pixels.

Divide the size (in pixels) of the ruler by 12.  That is the pixels per inch (aka dots per inch or DPI) of a picture of the ruler, when taken from the distance you measured with the tape measure.

**The point about needing 100 DPI** is that the OCR library needs sufficient resolution to recognize letters.  It probably wants the letters to be 15-20 pixels tall (I'm guessing).  If the letters are too small, the image may just not have enough information for the OCR library to work.  And the letters could also be too big - the library is probably not programmed to look for letters that are 100 pixels tall.  And if the letters are the right size, but blurry, the OCR library will probably not be able to recognize them.

It may simply be that you are trying to take a picture of text that is too small, so when you hold the camera close enough to make the letters the right size, the camera cannot focus and the picture is blurry.  In that case, there is probably nothing you can do to fix it (except get a phone with a better camera).

Answer (score 0):

It has 72 dpi, at least this is what does it store in EXIF
[image]

Comment: That's just a placeholder.  It doesn't represent the pixels per physical inch of the object in the photograph.

Comment: @robmayoff:Then what is the DPIs of my photo taken by iPhone

Comment: @VXtreme I answered that in my comment on your question.

Comment: I am taking a photo of card like small objects from just a half a foot  above it.can i get more than 100 dpis for this ? Where can i check it?

Comment: well, I belive this DPI thing is really obsolete on digital devices. this term is from printing world, but we're in the pixel world. I believe you can _assume_ that iPhone/iPad camera does not care about DPI either, so you can use a default (dummy, conventional, etc) value of 72 dpi